# Using the onchange event to get value of select color list in order to change a picture

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

I'm using a select list to change the color of a preview image of a picture of a shirt. So I have a global variable named chosenColor and I want to use that to change the picture when I select a color from the select list. It only works to change the color to blue but it won't work to change the color back to red.

This is the relevant javascript

```
var chosenColor="Red";

function chooseBlue() {
     document.getElementById("largerview").src = "bluezigzag.jpg";
     chosenColor = "Blue";
     }

function chooseRed() {
     document.getElementById("largerview").src = "redzigzag.jpg";
     chosenColor = "Red";
     }


function getSelectionChange() {      //selects the color that the user selects in the selection list
     if (this.value = "red") {
         chooseBlue();
         window.alert(chosenColor);
     }
     else if (this.value = "blue") {
         chooseRed();
         window.alert(chosenColor);
     }
}
```

And this is the selection list

```
<select size="1" name="color" onchange="getSelectionChange();">
     <option value="red">Red</option>
     <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `===` or `==`:

```
if (this.value = "red") {

...

else if (this.value = "blue") {
```

should be

```
if (this.value === "red") {

...

else if (this.value === "blue") {
```

When you use `this.value = "red"` it sets the value to `"red"` and then the expression returns `"red"` - which is truthy, so execution goes into that if block.

Have you considered replacing the separate choose colour functions with something like this:

```
function getSelectionChange() {
     document.getElementById("largerview").src = this.value + "zigzag.jpg";
     window.alert(this.value);
}
```

Obviously you could still set a global `chosenColor` variable, but I'm not sure what you'd need it for.

EDIT: Also if you are using an inline `onchange=` handler to call a function, `this` will be the element in question within the `onchange` attribute's code, but not in the function called from there - unless you explicitly set it:

```
onchange="getSelectionChange.call(this);"
```

Comment: +1 for the latter part, that's pretty much where I was going with my own (now deleted) answer.

Comment: Hah can't believe I made that mistake. I need to start thinking "gets" and "equals" in my head so I don't get them confused. Yeah I need the chosenColor variable for something else.

Comment: But now that I corrected my mistake and changed it to === the function does nothing at all.

Comment: Yes, see my edit. The reason it sort of "worked" before is that `this` was actually `window` so `this.value` was `undefined` - but `this.value = "red"` was creating a global variable and executing the `if` block. You need to ensure that `this` actually is the element in question.